# Transparent actionDropDown and overflow menu actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme, android-styles

I want to make actionbardropdown and overflow menu transparent How can I do this?

I have tried

```
   <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myactionbar</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/dropdown</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/popupmenucolor</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/myactionbar</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/dropdownlistview</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myactionbar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style> 

    <style name="dropdown" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/transparent_background</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/dropdown</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_colors</item>
    </style>

    <style name="dropdownlistview" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/dropdown</item>
    </style>

    <style name="popupmenucolor" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/dropdown</item>
    </style>
```

here @drawable/dropdown is a 9 patch semi transparent image which has 30% opacity

But it does not make the dropdown transparent. How can I get this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with a color with some alpha or maybe other drawables? Just to check if it isn't some problem with your drawable...

Comment: Hi @Mikel No matter what I set on drawables dropdown always has white background .